# For loop for an array is not working

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

[image: Image of array which is coming like this.]

I want to store all the studentId in one group

i have tried like this:

i am bit new with for/foreach loops.

```
if($_POST['action']=='startGdstudents')  {
parse_str($_POST['participantsForGd'], $participantsForGd);
$jobID  =   $participantsForGd['jobID'];                      // example: 85
$group  =   mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['group']); // example: 2

foreach ($participantsForGd as $k => $v){
    foreach ($v['StudentId'] as $studentid => $student){
    $q = $conn->query("INSERT INTO r_job_groups (student_id,job_id,group_id) VALUES (".$student.",".$jobID.",".$group.") ");
}
}
```

My errors:

> **Warning**:  Illegal string offset 'StudentId' in
>   **/home2/amerytec/public_html/lc-latest/gdcontroller .php** on line
>   **171**
>  
>  **Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() in **/home2/amerytec/public_html/lc-latest
>   /gdcontroller.php** on line **171**
>  
>  **Warning**: 
>   Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   **/home2/amerytec/public_html/lc-latest /gdcontroller.php** on line
>   **171**

Comment: have you got any errors?

Comment: print `$participantsForGd` and `$v` to debug

Comment: is my for loop is correct..?

Comment: If you say `foreach ($v['StudentId']...` then `$v` must be an array and key `StudentId` must exist. However, `$v` doesn't have a key `StudentId` at all. Try to `print_r()` or `var_dump()` the `$v` variable, and examine the type and value of `$v`.